# how to interpret data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have problem in interpret the following syntax:

```
data=data.frame(X,Z[,5])
```

I check it in R. I konw that X is the dataset that pass to the data.fram, but I don't find the corresoponding argument to `Z[,5]`, so how to interpret this syntax?

```
data.frame(..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
           check.names = TRUE, fix.empty.names = TRUE,
           stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())
```

Comment: `Z[,5]` is the 5th column of some `data.frame` named `Z`.

Comment: It says create a data.frame named data with columns `X` and `Z[, 5]` where `X` is a vector and `Z` is either a different data.frame or a matrix with the same number of rows as the length of `X`.

Comment: @lmo X need not be a column, it could be another data.frame with a bunch of cols, for example.

Comment: @Frank. That's amazing. I haven't thought the data.frame function in that context before. `data.frame(df1, df2)` is equivalent to `cbind(df1, df2)`. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Imo the two are not equivalent. `cbind` returns a matrix. `data.frame(df1,df2)` is equivalent to `data.frame(cbind(df1,df2))`

Comment: @Alex: not quite. The intermediate `cbind()` will do some coercion (e.g. try `str(cbind(f1=factor(1:3),f2=factor(2:4)))`)

Comment: Maybe equivalent to `cbind.data.frame()`, which works for Ben's exception.

Comment: @BenBolker I get class "matrix" and type `int` from your example. If I wrap that in `data.frame()` I get a "data.frame" with `int` variables `f1,f2`. `cbind.data.frame` does work

Answer (score 4):

`X` and `Z[,5]` are both being passed as data values through the `...` argument. An attempt will be made to make both of them into separate columns of a data frame.  Any arguments that follow `...` in an argument list must be named. In `data.frame()`, `...` is the first argument.  So to pass values to any argument other than `...`, you must use names.  You haven't named any, and therefore both `X` and `Z[,5]` are passed to `...`.  If you had done, for example,

```
data.frame(X, row.names = Z[,5])
```

where there is a named argument, then `Z[,5]` would be passed to the `row.names` argument.  See the [Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html) manual for more.

Comment: If the `x` and `z[,5]` are both passed to `...` , then the output will be the concatenation of them?

Comment: No, each one will be made into a column of the data frame.